# How to add jquery animation to bootstrap ajax tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have my set of a working jQuery ajax tabs. And I need a bit animation on the display. I tried many times to add an animation to it. It seems to work but a problem occurred - a tab it not unique. When I clicked a second tab, the content is not loaded into a new tab. But it's continue to display under the current content instead. Here's my code:

**Html**

```
<ul id="MainTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="inc/timetable_content_detail.php?id=1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" href="inc/timetable_content_detail.php?id=2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" href="inc/timetable_content_detail.php?id=3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" href="inc/timetable_content_detail.php?id=4">Tab 4</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#tab5" data-toggle="tab" href="inc/timetable_content_detail.php?id=5">Tab 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" style="background:#ffffff">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"><?include "inc/timetable_content_detail.php";?></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"><img src="images/loading.gif" />Loading...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3"><img src="images/loading.gif" />Loading...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4"><img src="images/loading.gif" />Loading...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5"><img src="images/loading.gif" />Loading...</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#MainTabs").tab();
  $("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {    
    var contentID  = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
    var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");
    $(contentID).load(contentURL, function(){
      $("#MainTabs").tab().slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
  $('#MainTabs a:first').tab("show");
});
```

I tried to add slideDown("slow") after a tab() but it seems not so right. Could you guy please have a look on my code and suggest.

Regards,

Comment: As a courtesy, please consider creating your best working example as a jsFiddle.